# website moved and php form not working (old php version)

Tags: php, forms

I moved website from to other hosting server and contact form doesn't work. Current version of php is 5.2 and before was older. I saw on forums that in order for older php code to work i should turn globals on which I did (I know it's insecure and I will replace that code completely, but right now I have to make it work). Before I turned globals on nothing was working and now I'm getting message if some field is missing but nothing more than that. Any suggestions how to make this contact form work? Any answer will be very appreciated.

```
<?
$contact = 'contact';

require('inc_meta.php');

if($form)
{
$error = Array();
if(!trim($c_name)){ $error[sizeof($error)] = "Name"; }
if(!trim($email)){ $error[sizeof($error)] = "E-mail Address"; }
else {
if(!eregi("^[_\.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,3}$",$email)){ $error[sizeof($error)] = "'" . $email . "' is not avalid E-mail Address."; }
}
}
$filePath = getenv("SCRIPT_NAME");
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].''.$filePath.'')
{
if($form && !$error)
{
$contents = "Name: $c_name\r
Address:\r
$c_address\r
$c_city, $c_state $c_zip\n
Phone: $c_phone\r
Fax: $c_fax\r
Email: $email\n
Comments or Questions:\r
$c_comments";

mail("$EMAILADMIN","email from $c_name","$contents","From: $c_name<$email>");

          $status = "Thank You, <b>$c_name</b><br><br>";
          $status .= "Your e-mail message has been sent. We will contact you shortly about your inquiry. ";
          $status .= "If you need more assistance or have questions, please call us at <b>1234567</b><br><br>";
          $status .= "Thank You,<br><b>Owner</b><br>";

}}
?>
<table width="860" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr valign="top"> 
    <td width="325"> 
      <? include('inc_sideBar.php'); ?>
    </td>
    <td width="535">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr> 
          <td> 
            <? include('inc_header.php'); ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td> 
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
              <tr> 
                <td align="center" valign="top"> 
                  <? if(!$status){ ?>
                  <br>
                  <table width="95%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr> 
                      <form name="form" method="post" action="<? echo $PHP_SELF; ?>">
                        <td> 
                          <? if(sizeof($error)){ ?>
                          <font color="#FADE82"><b> The following fields are still 
                          required:<br>
                          <?
         for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($error); $i++) {
         echo "&nbsp;*", "&nbsp;", $error[$i];
         }
         ?>
                          </b></font><br>
                          <br>
                          <? } ?>
                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
                            <tr> 
                              <td width="54%" valign="top"><font color="#FFF9DD">Name</font><font color="#CC0000"> 
                                <font color="#FADE82"></font></font><b><font color="#CC0000"><font color="#FADE82">*</font><br>
                                <input type="text" name="c_name" value="<? echo $c_name; ?>" size="23">
                                </font></b></td>
                              <td width="46%" valign="top"><font color="#FFF9DD">State</font><b><br>
                                </b> 
                                <select name="c_state">
                                  <option> 
                                  <? echo $c_state; ?>
                                  </option>
                                  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                                  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                                  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                                  <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                                  <option value="CA">California</option>
                                  <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                                  <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                                  <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                                  <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                                  <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                                  <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                                  <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                                  <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                                  <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                                  <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                                  <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                                  <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                                  <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                                  <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                                  <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                                  <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                                  <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                                  <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                                  <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                                  <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                                  <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                                  <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                                  <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                                  <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                                  <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                                  <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                                  <option value="NY">New York</option>
                                  <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                                  <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                                  <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                                  <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                                  <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                                  <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                                  <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                                  <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                                  <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                                  <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                                  <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                                  <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                                  <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                                  <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                                  <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                                  <option value="DC">Washington, D.C.</option>
                                  <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                                  <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                                  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                                </select>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                              <td valign="top" width="54%"><font color="#FFF9DD">E-mail</font><font color="#CC0000"> 
                                <font color="#FADE82"></font></font><b><font color="#CC0000"><font color="#FADE82">*</font> 
                                <br>
                                <input type="text" name="email" value="<? echo $email; ?>" size="23">
                                </font></b></td>
                              <td valign="top" width="46%"><font color="#FFF9DD">Zip</font><b><br>
                                </b> 
                                <input type="text" name="c_zip" value="<? echo $c_zip; ?>" size="20">
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                              <td valign="top" width="54%"><font color="#FFF9DD">Address</font><b><br>
                                <input type="text" name="c_address" value="<? echo $c_address; ?>" size="23">
                                </b></td>
                              <td valign="top" width="46%"><font color="#FFF9DD">Phone</font><b><br>
                                </b> 
                                <input type="text" name="c_phone" value="<? echo $c_phone; ?>" size="20">
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                              <td valign="top" width="54%"><font color="#FFF9DD">City</font><b><br>
                                <input type="text" name="c_city" value="<? echo $c_city; ?>" size="23">
                                </b></td>
                              <td valign="top" width="46%"><font color="#FFF9DD">Fax</font><b><br>
                                </b> 
                                <input type="text" name="c_fax" value="<? echo $c_fax; ?>" size="20">
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                              <td valign="top" width="54%">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td valign="top" width="46%">&nbsp; </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                              <td valign="top" colspan="2"> <font color="#FFF9DD">Comments 
                                or Questions?:</font><br>
                                <textarea name="c_comments" wrap="VIRTUAL" cols="30" rows="5"><? echo $c_comments; ?></textarea>
                                <br>
                                <br>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                              <td valign="top" colspan="2"> 
                                <input type="image" border="0" name="imageField" src="images/submit.gif" class="select">
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                          <input type="hidden" name="form" value="one">
                        </td>
                      </form>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <? }else{ ?>
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr> 
                      <td> <br>
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                          <tr> 
                            <td> 
                              <font color="#FFF9DD"><? echo $status; ?></font>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <? } ?>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
            <? include('footer_info.php'); ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<? require('inc_footer.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should access the form data using the $_POST array.
Read the Warning in this page of the php docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.predefined.php

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is nice resource if I'm interesting in changing code to match modern guidelines. Like I mentioned before, I will rewrite whole web site or make new one, but for now, I just need to make it work until I finish some more important stuff. Is it possible to make this code work on php 5.2 with some minor changes or with some changes in php settings or not? On the side security and other issues, can this be done? If not, tell me so, if yes, tell me how. Again, thank you for your feedback.

Comment: You can make it work by replacing all the variables coming from the form, like $c_name, and access them with $_POST['c_name']. But pay attentions, there are lots of changes between the older php versions and the current one.

Comment: OK, so no easy solution for this. Thank you very much for your answer.